# Unable to connect to AWS ec2 instance public ip via browser

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, telnet, ufw, openresty

I've newly installed Openresty as the web server on an ec2 instance and its currently running but I can't even view the welcome page when I try to navigate to it via my public ip address at the browser. Anyone can tell whats the issue I'm having?

So far I've tried these :

1. `telnet mypublicip` and it gets stuck on

`Trying mypublicip...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

2. Firewall is open but it should be okay I think, here is the output of `sudo uwf status`

Output:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

3. Here is the output of `sudo iptables -L`:

Output:

```
Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT                                          BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ubuntu@ip-10-110-100-100:/usr/local/openresty$ clear
ubuntu@ip-10-110-100-100:/usr/local/openresty$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: telnet to your public IP address? really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the ports on the security group that is attached to the instance

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Answer (score 2):

Telnet by default uses port 23. So if you don't specify a different port your want to telnet into it will use its default port which you don't have enabled there by the looks of it.

Also, you configured the rules in the OS firewall, but have you configured the security group of the ec2 instance do allow the incoming traffic on those ports as well ?
First thing I'd do is disable the firewall on the machine and configure the security group in AWS to allow the traffic. Once it's working you can start configuring internal firewall.